# Why does Tkinter stack overflow on Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, stack-overflow

This short Python script [debugwin.py](https://gist.github.com/3013616) works great on my Linux machine:

```
>>> import debugwin
>>> l = []
>>> debuwin.watch(l)
0
>>> l.append(1)
```

However, [people have told me](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/vrcnn/debugwin_live_watch_windows_for_python/) that on Windows (Python 2.7.3 Windows 7) it sometimes doesn't update after you append, and sometimes gets a stack overflow:

```
>>> error in background error handler:
    out of stack space (infinite loop?) while executing "::tcl::Bgerror {out of stack
    space (infinite loop?)} {-code 1 -level 0 -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {out of stack
    space (infinite loop?)Unable to format..."
```

How can the script overflow?

Answer (score 3):

It can overflow if the code that was written to report a bug has a bug. When it tries to report a bug it calls the bug reporting code, but it has a bug so it tries to call the bug reporting code, ... I'm not saying that's the problem, but that's at least one way to get what you're seeing.

I'm not particularly surprised you get crashes with the debugwin.py code you linked to (at least, the version of that code at the time I write this). Tkinter isn't thread safe, and conventional wisdom is that it should only be run in the main thread of an application. It looks like the code creates a tk interpreter in a sub-thread. So, even if there's no bug in the bug reporting code, the fact that the tcl interpreter is running in a sub-thread makes me think it could be thread-related. Certainly, the fact that the crash seems random leads me to believe it's related to threading.

I see another thing that looks somewhat suspicious. All widgets have an `update` method which calls the standard tk `update` command. You have a widget that inherits from Label, and you created your own `update` method. That may not cause any problems, but it's a code smell.

Comment: Googling, http://bugs.python.org/issue11077#msg127981 says Tkinter *is* thread safe (although its in a bug report, but still); is this blatantly wrong, or wishful thinking, or?  I also can't find any docs on the update command, but will try renaming it.  I'm really hoping I don't have to take the debugwin UI into multiprocessing yuck

Comment: Personally I think it's wrong. I've seen seemingly harmless tkinter code that crashes when run in a thread. I will admit, however, I do not know for certain. All I know is the couple of times I've tried threaded solutions, tkinter eventually (or sometimes immediately) crashes mysteriously (as is common with thread-unsafe code).